# Refer to a value just set in array within foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel-5

We've got a foreach loop that one of our console commands, it builds an array to be put in the database after being turned to Json.

In order to get one of the specific values, we'd like to reference two of the OTHER values that have been pulled in the loop

Below is the loop, the 'conversionRate' valus is what we're trying to get, from the result of the 'sales' and 'quotes' queries. I have no idea how to call those while still inside the loop.

```
 foreach ($users as $user) {
            $todaysCcActionsArray[] = [
                'name' => DB::Table('sw_users')->where('EmailAddress', $user)->value('FirstName'),

                'code' => $user,

                'sales' => Order::where('Status', 'BOOKING')
                ->whereNotIn('Product', ['commercial_insurance', 'home_insurance'])
                ->where('MasterOrderNumber', 0)
                ->whereNull('OriginalOrderNumber')
                ->where('CallCentreID', '!=', $user)
                ->whereDate('OrderDate', '=', date('Y-m-d'))->count(),

                'quotes' => Order::where('Status', 'QUOTE')
                ->whereNotIn('Product', ['commercial_insurance', 'home_insurance'])
                ->where('MasterOrderNumber', 0)
                ->whereNull('OriginalOrderNumber')
                ->where('CallCentreID', '!=', $user)
                ->whereDate('OrderDate', '=', date('Y-m-d'))->count(),

                'conversionRate' => 'sales' / 'quotes' * 100
            ];
        }
```

UPDATE

This Is how it comes out if printed.

```
array:16 [ 
        0 => array:4 [ 
                "name" => "Melissa" 
                "code" => "mkingnew" 
                "sales" => 2 
                "quotes" => 1 
                ] 
        1 => array:4 [ 
                "name" => "Wendy" 
                "code" => "wjonesnew" 
                "sales" => 2 
                "quotes" => 1 
                ] 
        2 => array:4 [ 
                "name" => "Sarah" 
                "code" => "sdickersonnew" 
                "sales" => 2 
                "quotes" => 1 ]
```

Comment: Do a `print_r()` on the array and work out where it is and what it is called in that array

Comment: `array:16 [
  0 => array:4 [
    "name" => "Melissa"
    "code" => "mkingnew"
    "sales" => 2
    "quotes" => 1
  ]
  1 => array:4 [
    "name" => "Wendy"
    "code" => "wjonesnew"
    "sales" => 2
    "quotes" => 1
  ]
  2 => array:4 [
    "name" => "Sarah"
    "code" => "sdickersonnew"
    "sales" => 2
    "quotes" => 1
  ]`

Is how it comes out if printed.

Comment: Right, so what is the problem?

Comment: Well, no matter how I call "sales" it seems to read it as a string, rather than an int, so it reads it as "sales" not as the value of sales. Im unsure of the exact syntax for calling here, which is why I asked the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're effectively doing is trying to create an array entry using values from itself whilst you're creating it... you can't do that :)

What you can do is build the entry in pieces, then add it to the array:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $entry = array(
        'name' => DB::Table('sw_users')->where('EmailAddress', $user)->value('FirstName'),
        'code' => $user,
        'sales' => Order::where('Status', 'BOOKING')
            ->whereNotIn('Product', ['commercial_insurance', 'home_insurance'])
            ->where('MasterOrderNumber', 0)
            ->whereNull('OriginalOrderNumber')
            ->where('CallCentreID', '!=', $user)
            ->whereDate('OrderDate', '=', date('Y-m-d'))->count(),

        'quotes' => Order::where('Status', 'QUOTE')
            ->whereNotIn('Product', ['commercial_insurance', 'home_insurance'])
            ->where('MasterOrderNumber', 0)
            ->whereNull('OriginalOrderNumber')
            ->where('CallCentreID', '!=', $user)
            ->whereDate('OrderDate', '=', date('Y-m-d'))->count(),
    );
    $entry['conversionRate'] = $entry['sales'] / $entry['quotes'] * 100; 

    $todaysCcActionsArray[] = $entry;
}
```

Comment: Aha! That worked an absolute treat thank you! Legend +1